# How to use filter value as variable in django orm

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-annotate

I want to use `tmp_id` as a value of `row id` in extra method .

**code:**

```
order_obj = table.objects.filter()
.annotate(
     tmp_id=F('table2__test_data')
)
.extra(
      select={"val":"select id from data where row_id = {{here i want to use 
      tmp_id}} limit 1"}
)
```

can anyone tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Can you explain more about your question?

Comment: i want to use tmp_id of .annotate in .extra  ....i.e every row contains different tmp_id and i want to pass that tmp_id to .extra function and get some diffrent value . @HamidrezaAhmadi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any solution where we can use temp_id directly but there is an alternative where i can directly specify table2.test_data in extra method given below .

```
order_obj = table.objects.filter()
.annotate(
     tmp_id=F('table2__test_data')
)
.extra(
      select={"val":"select id from data where row_id = table2.test_data limit 1"}
)
```